# Bluebird Promise.try rejection behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a setup very similar to this

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
function reject() {
    return Promise.reject("foo");
};
process.on("unhandledRejection", () => {
   console.log("Promise rejected");
});
Promise.try(() => {
   reject();
   return;
}).catch(console.log);
```

`.catch` catches the rejection and prints out the `foo` error message, but it also triggers `unhandledRejection`.
If I return that rejected Promise though, it works:

```
reject();
return;
```

would be changed to

```
return reject();
```

But the problem is, I need to catch non-returning Promise before returning another one..
Is this how bluebird's try supposed to work, or am I missing something?

Comment: "*`.catch` catches the rejection and prints out the "foo" error message*" - it should not. That's a bug. Please report it to the Bluebird repo.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I need to catch non-returning Promise*"? Do you want to ignore the first promise result (and not wait for it either), but log errors from it?

Comment: What version of bluebird do you use?  I tested your code and it shows `Promise rejected` for `reject(); return;`  and `foo`  for `return reject();`  and that is the expected result.

Comment: Its kinda different, I'm trying to catch all sync-async (I don't know how many errors will that block contain, I'm working on a private framework) errors in the Promise.try block, and no, not ignore them, just stop the execution of the block, like catch regularly does.. I suppose if this is the correct behaviour of bluebird, I will need to find another way. @Bergi

Comment: @t.niese let me check, could be an outdated version.. But I'm quite sure it isnt

Comment: You cannot catch asynchronous errors if they're not returned from the function as a promise (you'd look for domains not promises). You have to somehow compose all of them, using `Promise.all` or chaining or something. Maybe you are looking for `Promise.coroutine(function*(){ yield reject(); return; })().catch(console.error)`?

Comment: @Bergi, I will check out Promise.coroutine (I already tried co by tj, didnt really work in the way I wanted), I would really like to use domains for that block of code, but they are being deprecated, and I don't really know if the new replacement would contain the functionality I need, since a lot of people are using domains in the wrong way, leaking memory.

Comment: @Aurieh `Promise.coroutine` is not really different from `co.wrap`. Probably you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) stating [what functionality you actually need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).